# How to combine and calculate the average of three cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file where there are first four values and then three integers. I need to combine those three integers into one cell and in that cell needs to be their average. So from:

```
 - Gender |Age  |Country  |Score 1|Score 2|Score 3
 - male   |15   |NL       |1      |4      |1      |
 - male   |23   |NL       |3      |3      |2      |
 - female |34   |UK       |4      |3      |3      |
 - male   |53   |USA      |5      |4      |4      |
```

to:

```
 - Gender |Age  |Country  |Score 
 - male   |15   |NL       |2
 - male   |23   |NL       |3
 - female |34   |UK       |3
 - male   |53   |USA      |4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you add your code to your post, we'll be able to help you figure out what's going wrong. Most folks here, though, won't just write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following macro will do what you want.  You can call vba functions from the worksheets directly, but as you wanted to replace the cells, a function doesn't make sense.  I put the arguments for the loop in variables to make it easier to modify to suite your needs.

If you need it rounded, then do the rounding in the

```
 avg=avg/3
```

Line of the code.

```
Sub ConsolidatetoAvg()
     Dim StartingRow As Integer
         StartingRow = 2

         Dim EndingRow As Integer
         EndingRow = 5

         Dim StartingColumn As Integer
         StartingColumn = 4

         Dim index As Integer
         Dim x As Integer
         Dim avg As Double

         For index = StartingRow To EndingRow
             avg = 0
             For x = StartingColumn To StartingColumn + 3
                 avg = avg + Cells(index, x)
                 Cells(index, x) = ""
             Next
             avg = avg / 3
             Cells(index, StartingColumn) = avg
         Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile a formula option, assuming `- Gender` is in A1:

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(D2:F2),0)
```

in G2 and copied down to suit. Then ColumnG selected, Copy, Paste Special, Values, Columns D:F deleted and `Score` entered in D1.